# Powershell get total size of files which user owns

Tags: powershell, size

I need a powershell script, which will go through all users in system and will find total size of all files which any user own... I have script which is going through all users, but then I've no idea to continue with counting total size which user owns for each user

Here is a script, which I`ve now:

```
$users = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_UserAccount

foreach($user in $users) {
    $name = $user.Name
    $fullName = $user.FullName;
    if(Test-Path "C:\Users\$name") {
        $path = "C:\Users\$name"
    } else {
        $path = "C:\Users\Public"
    }

    $dirSize = (Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
 "{0:N2}" -f ($dirSize.sum / 1Gb) + " Gb"
echo "$dirSize"


Add-Content -path "pathototxt..." -value "$name $fullName $path"

}
```

I would be more than happy If somebody know the answer and tell me it...
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If there's a lot of files, you might want to consider:

```
$oSIDs = @{}

get-childitem <filespec> |
 foreach {
  $oSID = $_.GetAccessControl().Sddl -replace '^o:(.+?).:.+','$1'
  $oSIDs[$oSID] += $_.length
  }
```

Then resolve the SIDs when you're done.  Parsing the owner SID or well-know security principal ID from the SDDL string saves the provider from having to do a lot of repetitive name resolution to give you back the "friendly" names.

Comment: +1 Easy sid converter: `(new-object system.security.principal.securityidentifier($sid)).translate([system.security.principal.ntaccount])`

Comment: +1 Great work on the codes. :-) Just FYI, I used both your codes in a solution below where it's put together and modified. Not trying to be a thief, just providing a complete solution for him.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you're asking for here. 
`"to continue with counting total size which user owns for each user"`. huh? Do want to check every file on the system or just the userfolder as you currently do?

Your script works fine if you just tweak it to include the filesize in the output. Personally I'd consider using a csv to store this because not all users will have e.g. a full name(admin, guest etc.). Also, atm. your script is counting the public folder multiple times(each time a user doesn't have a profile). E.g. admin(if it has never logged in), guest etc. might both get it specified.

Updated script that outputs both textfile and csv

```
$users = Get-WmiObject -class Win32_UserAccount

$out = @()
#If you want to append to a csv-file, replace the $out line above with the one below
#$out = Import-Csv "file.csv"

foreach($user in $users) {
    $name = $user.Name
    $fullName = $user.FullName;
    if(Test-Path "C:\Users\$name") {
        $path = "C:\Users\$name"
    } else {
        $path = "C:\Users\Public"
    }

    $dirSize = (Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum)
    $size = "{0:N2}" -f ($dirSize.Sum / 1Gb) + " Gb"

    #Saving as textfile
    #Add-Content -path "pathototxt..." -value "$name $fullName $path $size"
    Add-Content -path "file.txt" -value "$name $fullName $path $size"

    #CSV-way
    $o = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Name = $name
    FullName = $fullName
    Path = $path
    Size = $size
    }

    $out += $o
}

#Exporting to csv format
$out | Export-Csv "file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**EDIT:** Another solution using the answer provided by @mjolinor and @C.B. modified to scan your `c:\` drive while excluding some "rootfolders" like "program files", "windows" etc. It exports the result to a csv file ready for Excel.:

```
$oSIDs = @{}

$exclude = @("Program Files", "Program Files (x86)", "Windows", "Perflogs"); 

Get-ChildItem C:\ | ? { $exclude -notcontains $_.Name } | % { Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } } | % {
  $oSID = $_.GetAccessControl().Sddl -replace '^o:(.+?).:.+','$1'
  $oSIDs[$oSID] += $_.Length
  }

$out = @()
$oSIDs.GetEnumerator() | % { 
    $user = (New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($_.Key)).Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
    $out += New-Object psobject -Property @{
        User = if($user) { $user } else { $_.Key }
        "Size(GB)" = $oSIDs[$_.Key]/1GB
    }
}

$out | Export-Csv file.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"
```

Comment: I know, that this, what I programmed is almost correct. But I need to do next part, which is count size of all files in system, where current(ith) user is owner. And so far I don't know this.

Comment: do you have any specific folders? Can you exclude "program files", "windows" etc.? are there multiple disks?

Comment: It wasn't told me which folder should it go through. That's why I thought, that it should go through whole file system. But it`s probably absurdity.. So then I think it could start at home folder and  include all subfolders in this

Comment: you will hit so many access-denied errors and lots of unnecessary load if you don't exclude folders like "program files", "windows". try mjolinor's answer something like this to search through `c:\ ` wile excluding those folders: `$ex = @("Program Files", "Program Files (x86)", "Windows", "Perflogs"); Get-ChildItem c:\ | ? { $ex -notcontains $_.Name } | % { Get-ChildItem $_ -Recurse | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | ......his code}`

Comment: I'm new in powershell, so I don't know exact structure of this, but I can't find there where is condition that will be used only files which the user is owner?

Comment: ? I don't follow. my answer was only an update of yours(only counting profile-folder). If you need to check all files, try to use the code in my last comment and replace `....his code` with the `foreach` part in mjolinor's code (remember to include `$oSIDs = @{}` at the start of the script

Comment: I've updated my answer to search the complete `c:\ ` drive, excluding the folders that I advised you to do. It uses the answers suggested by @mjolinor and @C.B. , cleans up the results and saves it as a csv file.